# Pivot Table - Keys from multiple columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I've been trying to build a pivot table that uses keys from multiple columns.

This would be the source table (Items 1,2,3 columns represent the keys):

[[image: [1]]

This would be the resulting Pivot Table (The pivot table consolidates key "A" even though it is placed in other columns) :

[image: ""]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC1Rz.png)

Sorry if this is a terribly easy one to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a consolidation range pivot table. Alt+DP, then choose consolidation ranges as the source and add each pair of columns separately. You'll need the pairs of columns to all have the same headers.

Note also that consolidation range pivots are quite limited in terms of what you can do with them.

Comment: That was pretty simple!  It wasn't working because the headers for each columns had different names. Thank you very much for the help!