# Pivot table: Creating a unique data list and sum totals from data set (all with a filter!)

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am looking to create a consolidated pivot table (similar to the one shown in [Pivot Table - Keys from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855906/pivot-table-keys-from-multiple-columns)) but the source table also contains another column which lists  department names. I'm struggling to create the consolidated pivot table which includes a filter (or slicer) based on the department name.
Does any one have any ideas on how to solve this?
Let me know if you need more info.
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to UnPivot your source data before you create your PivotTable. If you give Google a spin on "VBA" and "UnPivot" you'll turn up some great code, including these:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/ (Look for the code block at the bottom below the 'Update 26 November 2013' heading)
http://yoursumbuddy.com/data-normalizer/